# using pdftotext in Windows vs. Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-12.04, pdftotext

On my Windows 7 PC the command line input "pdftotext myfile.pdf" creates a .txt file in the same directory as myfile.pdf.  However, when I try the same command line input on my ubuntu-12.04 server with an identical myfile.pdf, I get an error output as follows:

```
Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error (2): Illegal character <21> in hex string
Error (4): Illegal character <4f> in hex string
Error (6): Illegal character <54> in hex string
Error (7): Illegal character <59> in hex string
Error (8): Illegal character <50> in hex string
Error (11): Illegal character <48> in hex string
Error (12): Illegal character <54> in hex string
Error (13): Illegal character <4d> in hex string
Error (14): Illegal character <4c> in hex string
Error (16): Illegal character <50> in hex string
Error (17): Illegal character <55> in hex string
Error (19): Illegal character <4c> in hex string
Error (20): Illegal character <49> in hex string
Error (23): Illegal character <22> in hex string
Error (24): Illegal character <2d> in hex string
Error (25): Illegal character <2f> in hex string
Error (26): Illegal character <2f> in hex string
Error (27): Illegal character <57> in hex string
Error (30): Illegal character <2f> in hex string
Error (31): Illegal character <2f> in hex string
Error (33): Illegal character <54> in hex string
Error (36): Illegal character <48> in hex string
Error (37): Illegal character <54> in hex string
Error (38): Illegal character <4d> in hex string
```

and so on...

```
Error (122): Illegal character <6c> in hex string
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Is the Windows 7 pdf utility package different than that available on Linux (which is from Poppler)?  Otherwise, the same call should produce the same result, no?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the file you're trying as input is not a PDF file.

It starts with (spaces are unknown characters)

```
 ! O TYP  HTML PU LI  "-//W  // T  HTM
```

...which can quickly(?) be interpreted as...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML
```

so it's most likely an error page from downloading the PDF. Either case, it's an HTML file, not a PDF.